# Como converter String minúscula para MAIÚSCULA?

Tags: java, string, orientação-a-objetos

A minha dúvida é no `switch (opcao)`. Para realizar um dos casos é necessário entrar com letras MAIÚSCULA. Existe alguma função de conversão de strings ou caracteres em Java de minúsculo para maiúsculo como no C (`tolower` e `toupper`).

Se existir apenas para caracteres, o `nextLine()` (permitido apenas para String) para inserir valor eu terei que mudar para o quê?

```
    package jjoi; 
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class principal {
    //i. incluir clientes na lista (informando somente nome e bairro)
    //ii. incluir funcionários na lista (informando somente nome, bairro e setor em que trabalha)
    //iii. apresentar todas as pessoas na lista que moram em um determinado bairro (informado pelo usuário)
     public static void main(String[] args){
     Scanner entrada= new Scanner(System.in);
     String opcao; 
     System.out.println("MENU DE ESCOLHAS");
     System.out.println("A- INCLUIR CLIENTES NA LISTA");
     System.out.println("B- INCLUIR FUNCIONARIOS NA LISTA");
     System.out.println("C- APRESENTAR TODAS AS PESSOAS NA LISTA QUE MORAM EM UM DETERMINADO BAIRRO");
     opcao=entrada.nextLine();
     switch(opcao)
     {
     case "A": System.out.println("INCLUINDO CLIENTES NA LISTA..."); 
     break;
     case "B": System.out.println("INCLUINDO FUNCIONARIOS NA LISTA..."); 
     break;
     case "C": System.out.println("APRESENTANDO TODAS AS PESSOAS NA LISTA 
     QUE MORAM EM UM DETERMINADO BAIRRO..."); 
     break;

     }
 }
 }
```

Comment: `String c = "ABC"; c = c.toLowerCase();`

Comment: No caso, para maiúsculas é `.toUpperCase()`. E eu uso quando há necessidade aqui o trampo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Com `.toUpperCase` e `.trim()` (dica do [Jefferson](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/64969/jefferson-quesado)), assim:

```
System.out.println("MENU DE ESCOLHAS");
System.out.println("A- INCLUIR CLIENTES NA LISTA");
System.out.println("B- INCLUIR FUNCIONARIOS NA LISTA");
System.out.println("C- APRESENTAR TODAS AS PESSOAS NA LISTA QUE MORAM  EM UM DETERMINADO BAIRRO");

String opcao = entrada.nextLine().toUpperCase().trim();
```

### Extra:

Não esqueça de adicionar o `default:` ao teu `switch` acaso o usuário digite algo que não contém em seu `switch`:

```
switch(opcao)
{
case "A": System.out.println("INCLUINDO CLIENTES NA LISTA..."); 
break;
case "B": System.out.println("INCLUINDO FUNCIONARIOS NA LISTA..."); 
break;
case "C": System.out.println("APRESENTANDO TODAS AS PESSOAS NA LISTA 
QUE MORAM EM UM DETERMINADO BAIRRO..."); 
break;
default: System.out.println("Digite uma opção valida");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Utilize a função `toUpperCase()`.

Assim:

```
opcao=entrada.nextLine().toUpperCase()
```

Comment: opcao=entrada.nextLine().toUpperCase().trim(); (Deu certo valeu!)

Comment: @Mauricio não foi exatamente o que eu respondi -.-'

Comment: @Mauricio, fico feliz em ter ajudado